# How can I respond to the frond-end request only after getting expected response from my database server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, backend, pg

I am trying create a pure Node.js HTTP server to connect my AngularJS Front-End to Postgres Database. But I unable to send a valid response to Front-End as the response to the Front-End gets sent before I could response from DB server.

My Back-End server code is as follows.

```
const http = require('http');
const pg = require('pg');

let menu = [];

const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000,
    'Content-Type':'application/JSON',
};

http.createServer((req, res) =>{

    client.connect();
    client.query('select * from menu;')
     .then(res => {
        for(row of res.rows) {
            let obj =   {
                            'name': row.name,
                            'price': row.price,
            };
            menu.push(obj);
        }
        console.log(menu);
        client.end().then(()=>{console.log("Database disconnected");});
     }).catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
    console.log(menu);
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.write(JSON.stringify(menu));
    res.end();
}).listen(3500, ()=>{
    console.log("BackEnd Server online");
});
```

The console logs from by Back-End is as follows. Kindly suggest me a possible fix.

```
BackEnd Server online
[]
[
  { name: 'Panner Butter Masala', price: 130 },
  { name: 'Dosa', price: 80 },
  { name: 'Roti', price: 40 },
  { name: 'Pulka', price: 30 },
  { name: 'Sambar vada', price: 70 }
]
Database disconnected
```

As you can see, before I can get a response from my DB, the response to my front-end already gets sent. So, I am unable to get the requested data.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that has nothing to do with what he asked! people want to learn and create their own servers. Ive built 2 REST API frameworks by myself just to  learn.

Comment: It has everything to do with what he asked: if this is a "because I want to see if I can" post, that should be _in the post_. It is currently not, and so as someone who gets paid to write this kind of code, my professional advice is to not do this, and that's _important advice to get_ because even though it's less fun, it also important to build the skills that others will need you to have. So in the absence of information: let's not assume anything about why they're doing this. Instead, let's _ask_ why they're doing this. Hence the comment. Serious question: why?

Comment: @Talg123 Thanks for the answer. The server works fine for the first ping but fails for consecutive pings. I get this error."Error: Client was closed and is not queryable". So, my question is: how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async/await to wait for the response and then send to the client

```js
const http = require('http');
const pg = require('pg');

let menu = [];

const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000,
    'Content-Type':'application/JSON',
};

http.createServer(async (req, res) =>{

    client.connect();
    try {
        const res = await client.query('select * from menu;');
        for(row of res.rows) {
            let obj = {
                'name': row.name,
                'price': row.price,
            };
            menu.push(obj);
        }   
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.stack);
    }
    await client.end();
    console.log("Database disconnected")
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.write(JSON.stringify(menu));
    res.end();
}).listen(3500, ()=>{
    console.log("BackEnd Server online");
});
```